# View Object refactoring/moving in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I have a View Object which need to be refactored and moved to another package.
Will refactoring the VO also make the necessary changes to its VOImpl class and SDO files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, all the parts of the VO definition are moved. Notice the "+" sign to the left of the VO name. If you click this it expands and shows all the files that make up the VO definition.

When you move an object via refactoring all the files contained in the object are moved and all references to it anywhere in the model are made. This [post](https://technology.amis.nl/2008/02/15/fear-for-renaming-refactoring-adf-bc-objects-in-jdeveloper-is-not-unfounded/) has some details that might be useful -but note the date as you do not mention your ADF version. Always indicate the version when asking questions here. 
Also the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/adf/develop/adf-web-refactoring.htm#ADFFD19704).